# How to Write a Migration which can add on update attribute to a column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migration

Im trying to write a migration to get a db column as shown in the Pic.
[image]

the on update attribute for date column..Can i set it by writing a migration? If so please help

Comment: Just a guess.Try `:default=>'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'`

Comment: @Pavan dont think it will work.. ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is coming under extra.. not under Default.. Click on the image.. It will expand

Comment: I have searched through many links,it is the default value.If you are using MySQL,try to run an empty migration and in the `up` method give like this `execute "CREATE TABLE your_table (field_name timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);"` and run `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: I'm using `Postgresql`,it didn't worked for me because `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is `MYSQL` specific,just try and tell me.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is MySQL specific, you'll need to execute the actual SQL within your migration. Try this

```
def up
  execute "ALTER TABLE orders ADD date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
end

def down
  remove_column :orders, :date
end
```

As an alternative approach, you could handle the updating of the date column within the application level vs. doing it at the database level. Just a thought.